# Proof of the Uniqueness of Dimension of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I suppose I should've posted this first but whatever. Here's what I'm trying to prove:

If $(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ and $(w_1,w_2,....,w_m)$ are bases of $V$, where V is a vector space, then $m = n$.

---

My Proof Attempt:

Let $(v_1,v_2,....,v_n)$ and $(w_1,w_2,....,w_m)$ be bases. Then, by the Exchange Lemma, there exists a $w_j$ for each $v_i$ such that if I replace $v_i$ with $w_j$, the resulting list still forms a basis for $V$. In that case, we need $(w_1,w_2,...,w_m)$ to have at least n vectors. Hence, $m \geq n$.

Similarly, by the Exchange Lemma, there exists a $v_i$ for each $w_j$ such that if I replace $w_j$ with $v_i$, the resulting list still forms a basis for $V$. In that case, we need $(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ to have at least m vectors Hence, $n \geq m$.

Since, $m \geq n$ and $n \geq m$, we conclude that $m = n$.

Once again, the proof given in the book was different but I tried proving this on my own first. Can someone have a look and see if it's fine? Thanks.

Comment: This shifts the problem of the uniqueness of dimension to the validity of the Steinitz exchange lemma.

Comment: Do you only care about the case of finite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: Well, that's what the book is discussing for the moment. I don't think Infinite Dimensional Vector Spaces are going to be mentioned anytime soon.

Comment: You can save yourself some work by assuming that $n\leq m$ at the outset (which one can do, by exchanging the roles in the first place). You can also avoid the exchange lemma if you know that a homogeneous system of linear equations with more unknowns than equations always has nontrivial solutions, as that implies if $W$ is linearly independent and $S$ spans, then $|W|\leq|S|$.

Comment: Hmm, that was the proof given by the book. It proved it by contradiction, which I perfectly understand. 

The proof using a property of homogeneous systems seems nice but the book hasn't done homogeneous systems yet. So, I can't use that. Would my proof, however, be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest method is that in the textbook of **A. Maltsev** *“Foundations of Linear Algebra”.* However, it is in Russian. An English adaptation of that proof is given as **Theorem 11.23** on page 112 in lecture notes *[“Linear Algebra, Theory and Algorithms”.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318066716_Linear_Algebra_Theory_and_Algorithms)*

Comment: Oooh interesting. However, I was just wondering if my proof was correct or not? I'm more concerned about the correctness of my proof (since that's a display of my own progress in the subject) as opposed to the actual proof (though I'm still very concerned about this).

Comment: Well, as the Steinitz exchange lemma you use has many forms, can you please indicate the exact form you use?

Comment: Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over F. If $(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ and $(u_1,u_2,.....,u_m)$ are bases for V, then for every $v_i$, there exists a $u_j$ such that exchanging $v_i$ with $u_j$ in the first list will still yield a basis for V. I haven't written it down exactly as it appeared in my textbook (Linear Algebra by Klaus Janich) because he uses different letters for the vectors in the second list. But everything else is the same.

Comment: I asked to re-state the Steinitz exchange lemma because it is known in different formats, which you can easily find in Wikipedia. So from now on we are based on what you above mentioned. I will insert my answer in a few portions, as it is longer than the limit.

Comment: If the first basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ has $n$ vectors, and the second basis $\{u_1, \ldots, u_m\}$ has $m$ vectors, and if these numbers are not equal, then without loss of generality we may assume $n<m$. Then by the above lema replace each of $ v_1, \ldots, v_n $ by a vector from the second basis. This will output a new bases which consists of $n$ vectors from the second basis (or less than $n$ vectors, if a vector was used twice).

Comment: So it turns out that a proper subset of the second basis is a basis itself, which is impossible because then all vectors of the second basis need be spanned by them (i.e., the second basis would be... linearly dependent).

Comment: Your proof is exactly correct. But is puts 90% of the whole job on the shoulders of the Steinitz exchange lemma the proof of which is much longer.

Comment: I still find much more reasonable, elegant, and shorter to use A. Maltsev's idea, which can be found in proof is given as Theorem 11.24 on page 109 in lecture notes “Linear Algebra, Theory and Algorithms”.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I will certainly look at those ideas in there. More recently, I’m less inclined to move on without gaining multiple perspectives on a given theorem or proof of a theorem.

Comment: I just read the respective sections from Jänich's book. Firstly:
His proof of why two bases have the same number of vectors (page 46) practically do not differ from *your* proof above.

Comment: And secondly, his proof (page 51-53) is interesting, and not very long. But I still like the version I mentioned earlier most.

Comment: I checked that book a little more. Well, I definitely don't have the right to give a feedback on this very serious book after spending just an hour on it. However, I noticed that under *spaces* it understands spaces over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, with no other fields evolved, including the modular finite fields $\mathbb Z_p$. 

From these day's perspective this seems to be a shortcoming because the modular approaches have very big applications in applied mathematics, computer algebra, etc...

Comment: Oh but my proof would count as more of a direct proof no? His was done by contradiction? Also, yea his book doesn’t really cover vector spaces over arbitrary fields. But there are sections for mathematicians and physicists in each chapter that cater to specific modes of thought. In those sections for mathematicians, he does aim to cover things in greater generality. I’m also using Paul Halmos’s Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces as a supplement for additional insight.

Comment: By the way, I had a look at your lecture notes and I think they’re really neat. Seem to fit me exactly when it comes to my learning style. I’ll probably use them a lot more for a 3rd perspective. I only wish they were published as a book (I’d rather buy the book than print out the lecture notes).

Comment: Hmm another thing: would you have any recommendations for linear algebra textbooks written for a pure mathematician? Like, for someone who wants to become a mathematician?

Comment: Yes, in the proof he us using contrapositive, but your proof basically is the variation of the same mathematical idea viewed at a different angle. Represented differently.

Comment: I now found the section “2.5 Fields” in his book. Yes, he covers spaces on abstract fields, too. And it is funny to COMPARE his remark in the frame on page 28 with my Agreement 4.3 on page 43 (in my Lecture Notes).

Comment: Thank you for checking my Lecture Notes. They mainly are an introduction to Linear Algebra, as some of my students are freshmen. However, I manage to evolve spaces on fields and also include diagonalization and orthogonal diagonalization. And all this in 35 lectures, one semester. Will get the Lecture Notes printed some day later.

Comment: Of advanced linear algebra books I was most impressed by 
Hoffman, Kenneth M.; Kunze, Ray, Linear_Algebra.
AND
Alexandr I. Kostrikin, Yu I Manin, Linear Algebra and Geometry.

Comment: As to recommendation for pure mathematician. You should just first find your principal research field, and then you will see which advanced segments of linear algebra (and other disciplines) are needed for your research.

Comment: For example, my research is in group theory, and there I found so many applications of linear algebra over finite fields, including representations of groups over vector spaces on finite fields. But as a student I did NOT learn linear algebra on abstract fields, at all! Instead, I learned the Jordan canonical form, which I never used in my research. So these examples are to show that one’s principal research field determines the segments that he should learn from other disciplines.

Comment: Ah interesting. Thank you for the recommendations

Comment: Hmm, I never really like Hoffman’s textbook. I’ll have a look at the other one, cos it seems pretty cool. I’m not in uni yet so i’m not too sure about what I’ll do research in. The goal is to go into pure mathematics and theoretical physics

Comment: Good luck in that hard trip!